# DVD writer doesn't work, no USB driver available

Tags: system-installation

First off, I'm new to this, so bear with me.
I'm a regular home PC user, not a developer or IT guru or computer whiz.

Trying to get and use Ubuntu for the first time. Downloaded it. Great. Didn't realize that I HAD to use the DVD writer on my computer, which gave up for some reason about six months ago. I have no USB drive available.

I have a Moto X, unrooted, uncustomized, nothing fancy, as it came in the box from the factory, except for Nova launcher and a keyboard.

My laptop is a Toshiba satellite C655. Cheap Walmart special.

Is there any way I can try to use my phone to install Ubuntu on my laptop, or would it just be best to just go get a flash drive tomorrow?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend borrowing a friends Pc to either burn a bootable Ubuntu DVD or Flash drive then booting from either one on your Toshiba laptop to test out and install...

Answer (score 0):

To be able to install Ubuntu on your computer you will need a DVD ROM or a USB Flash Drive. I think it's better to buy a USB Flash Drive. Just to know, a 16gb USB Flash Drive costs about 10$ and it will be useful for many other jobs. It's a must have nowadays...  :)